# Variable dependent rule in jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asynchronous

I have a problem with asynchronously validating login in my html form using jQuery Validation Plugin. I want it to send the request asking for login validity on blur, and validate when recieving a response.

This is my code:

```
var loginAvailability = false;

$().ready(function() {

    var gotResponse = false;

    $("#form").validate({

        onkeyup:false,

        rules: {
            login: {
                required: true,
                loginAvailable: gotResponse
            }
        },

        messages: {
            login: {
                required: "Please enter your login.",
                loginAvailable: "This login is already in use."
            }
        }
    });

    $("#login").blur(function() {
        if($('#login').val()) {
            var value = $('#login').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "my server adress"+value,
                data: "",
                success:function(data){
                    gotResponse = true;
                    loginAvailability = data[value] === false;
                    $("#form").validate().element("#login");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

$.validator.addMethod( "loginAvailable", function( value, element ) {
    return loginAvailability;
});
```

The response from the server is in json format looking like this:

```
{"chosenLogin": false}
```

Where *false* is for a free login, and *true* is for taken.

I've tested it by putting some *console.info()* lines inside to see what is happening and the problem is that it never goes to *loginAvailable* method, so it seems like the rule is never triggered. What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe to have found an answer. It was as simple as replacing:

```
loginAvailable: gotResponse
```

with

```
loginAvailable: {
                depends: function() {
                    return gotResponse;
                }
            }
```